# Conditional ElasticSearch sorting by different fields if in range

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I do have have products and some of them are reduced in price for a specific date range.
(simplified) example products:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "price": 2.0,
  "specialPrice": {
    "fromDate": null,
    "tillDate": null,
    "value": 0,
  },
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "price": 4.0,
  "specialPrice": {
    "fromDate": 1540332000,
    "tillDate": 1571781600,
    "value": 2.5,
  },
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "price": 3.0,
  "specialPrice": {
    "fromDate": null,
    "tillDate": null,
    "value": 0,
  },
}
```

Filtering by price was no problem. That I could do with a simple bool query.

But I could not yet find a good example for ElasticSearch scripts that could point me in the right direction, even though it should be quite simple, given you know the syntax.

My pseudocode: `price = ('now' between specialPrice.fromDate and specialPrice.tillDate) ? specialPrice.value : price`

Is there a way to translate this into something that would work in an ElasticSearch sorting?

To clarify further: By default, all products are already sorted by several conditions. The user can also search for any terms and filter the results while also being able to select multiple sorting parameters. Items can for example be sorted by tags and then by price, it's all very dynamic and it does still sort those results by some other properties (including the _score) afterwards.
So just changing the _score would be bad, since that is already calculated in a complex matter to show the best results for the given search terms.

Here is my current script, which does fail at the first `params.currentDate`:

```
"sort": {
"_script": {
  "type": "number",
  "script": {
    "source": "if(doc['specialPrice.tillDate'] > params.currentDate) {params.currentPrice = doc['specialPrice.value']} return params.currentPrice",
    "params": {
      "currentDate": "now",
      "currentPrice": "doc['price']"
    }
  }
}
```

---

**How it does work now:**
One problem was the nesting of some of the properties.
So one of my steps was to duplicate their content to new fields for the product (which I'm not that happy about, but whatever).
So in my mapping, I created new properties for products (specialFrom, specialTill, specialValue) and gave the corresponding fields in my specialPrice "copy_to" properties with the new property names.
The part is in php array syntax, since I'm using ruflin/elastica:

```
            'specialPrice' => [
                'type' => 'nested',
                'properties' => [
                    'fromDate' => [
                        'type' => 'date',
                        'format' => 'epoch_second',
                        'copy_to' => 'specialFrom',
                    ],
                    'tillDate' => [
                        'type' => 'date',
                        'format' => 'epoch_second',
                        'copy_to' => 'specialTill',
                    ],
                    'value' => [
                        'type' => 'float',
                        'copy_to' => 'specialValue',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'specialFrom' => [
                'type' => 'date',
                'format' => 'epoch_second',
            ],
            'specialTill' => [
                'type' => 'date',
                'format' => 'epoch_second',
            ],
            'specialValue' => [
                'type' => 'float',
            ],
```

Now my sorting sorting script does look like this (in my testing client, still working on implementing it within elastica):

```
"sort": {
"_script": {
  "type": "number",
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "params.param = ((doc['specialTill'].value - new Date().getTime()) > 0 && (new Date().getTime() - doc['specialFrom'].value) > 0) ? doc['specialValue'].value : doc['price'].value; return params.param;",
    "params": {
      "param": 0.0
    }
  }
}
```

}

I'm not 100% happy with this because I have redundant data and scripts (calling `new Date().getTime()` twice in the script), but it does work and that is the most important thing for now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the below query post your clarifications. Let me know if that works!

```
POST dateindex/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  // you can ignore this, I used this to test at my end

      }
   },
   "sort":{  
      "_script":{  
         "type":"number",
         "script":{  
            "lang":"painless",
            "inline":" params.param = ((doc['specialPrice.tillDate'].value - new Date().getTime()) > 0) ? doc['specialPrice.value'].value : doc['price'].value; return params.param;",
            "params":{  
               "param":0.0
            }
         },
         "order":"asc"
      }
   }
}
```

You can try using `source` instead of `inline` in the above query as I've been testing on `ES5.X` version on my machine.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if this does really help me in my case. I would have expected something like this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting

From how I understand your answer, I would have to update the price of all my products every time I want to sort by price. That does not seem very efficient to me ;)
I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: @Fanmade just to be clear, you don't want to update the price. Just want sorting and it should work as per psuedo-code you've provided?

Comment: That is correct. If the user chooses to sort by price, ElasticSearch should use the "special price" if it is valid at the current date and the normal price otherwise :)

Comment: @Fanmade Please check my answer now. I've updated another solution. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Your query would override the _score and always place reduced products at the top, right?
That's still not what I intent to get. If I understand it correctly, it would show the reduced article with the id 2 of my example first, and then all the other results.
For me, the reduced article should be on second place, since the one with id 1 is still cheaper, even if not reduced in price. Also, I'm still using the original _score after the custom sorting, since there are a lot of products with equal prices and within those I need to show the best results for the current search query.

Comment: @Fanmade I've updated my answer again. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience! :D
Based on your updated script I finally managed to make it work with my data and I've updated my answer accordingly.